# Is ROCR applied to training data or testing data?

Tags: rocr

Is ROCR applied to training data or testing data? Why?

Thank you,

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "ROCR."  It would appear to be an `R` *package,* not a statistical procedure.

Comment: ROCR is for evaluating classifier performance.  It stands for Receiver Operating Charaxteristic.  There is a lot about it on Wikipedia, although not the answer to my question.

Comment: ROC is a very general concept.  Perhaps you could edit your post to provide some context for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in R if you want to use the `ROCR` package, you use it on your test data. I think it is crucial to understand the steps involved prior to the plotting of the ROC curve.

1. You divide your data into `train data` and `test data`.
2. You do whatever regression on your `train data`.
3. Now, with the model (step 2) that you have just 'trained' on your `train data`, you can now use it predict the outcome of your dependent variable based on all the independent variables from your `test data`.
4. After you have your predicted outcome of the dependent variable, you create a confusion matrix to see how well you have predicted compared to your `test data`.
5. And, only now you can start to look into the ROC plot and AUC based on your prediction and your `test data`.

Below is a code for further elaboration, here `glmnet` is used, where `newx` is set to be the `test data`:

```
training.samples <- df$dependent %>% createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- df[training.samples, ]
test <- df[-training.samples, ]
x.train <- data.frame(train[, names(train) != "dependent"])
y.train <- train$dependent
x.test <- data.frame(test[, names(test) != "dependent"])
y.test <- test$dependent
model <- glmnet(x.train, y.train, family = "whatever you need")
coef <- coef(model, s = lambda.1se)
predicted <- predict(model, s = lambda.1se, newx = x.test)
t <- 0.4
predict_binary <- ifelse(predicted > t, 1, 0)
CM <- confusionMatrix(as.factor(predict_binary), as.factor(y.test))
pred <- prediction(predict_binary, y.test)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf)
auc_ROCR <- performance(pred, measure = "whatever you need")
auc_ROCR <- auc_ROCR@y.values[[1]]
auc_ROCR
```